# Numpy finding the number of points within a specific distance in absolute value

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, distance

I have a bumpy array.  I want to find the number of points which lies within an epsilon distance from each point.

My current code is (for a n*2 array, but in general I expect the array to be n * m)

```
epsilon = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
np.array([ 1/np.float(np.sum(np.all(np.abs(X-x) <= epsilon, axis=1))) for x in X])
```

But this code might not be efficient when it comes to an array of let us say 1 million rows and 50 columns.  Is there a better and more efficient method ?

Comment: Can you also provide example data for `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example data

```
X = np.random.rand(10, 2)
```

you can solve this using broadcasting:

```
1 / np.sum(np.all(np.abs(X[:, None, ...] - X[None, ...]) <= epsilon, axis=-1), axis=-1)
```